# VBScript to get links or attachments from a web page

Tags: vbscript

Does anyone have a VB Script that can get the most current/updated page or child page from a web site, then scan that page for a specific text that has a link or attachment?  Usually a child page gets add  on this web site. There are 4 folder link that have a specific text that we read and get the link info.
Example:
News: \\Network\drive\201405\14

The other updated page will have a attachment added so we need to download the most current attachment from a list of attachments.

Is there an easy automated way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

The only way to do what u ask for is to use classic ASP, because this only implementation supports Document Object Model. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892161/asp-classic-xml-dom) topic for example.

Comment: -1 That's not true. You can parse the HTML from most websites and even submit content/grab linksand extract data from live websites with just pure vbs. Classic ASP is a server-side language and utilizes vbs as it's supporting language. Also, most .Net supported languages can manage webpage parsing as well. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e036b5d9-1a70-4181-b68e-a80042501859/parse-data-from-html-file-using-vbscript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343853/access-form-elements-on-different-frames-in-vbscript/23349385#23349385 http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html